# Easiest way to evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/6}\sec x\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

Per the question title, what's the easiest way to evaluate the following?
$$\int_0^{\pi/6}\sec x\,dx$$

You can do something like computing the derivatives of $\sec x$ and $\tan x$, adding them up, computing the derivative of the logarithm of the absolute value of the sum of $\sec x$ and $\tan x$, and then completing the integration-by-parts, getting the final answer of $\ln(\sqrt{3})$.

But that feels like pulling something out of thin air.

I'm wondering if there's an easier way to compute the integral.

Comment: The way I learnt at school was $\int \sec x \, dx = \int \sec x \frac{\sec x + \tan x}{\sec x + \tan x} \, dx = \int  \frac{\sec^2 x + \sec x  \tan x}{\sec x + \tan x} \, dx = \ln (\sec x + \tan x)$ but I agree that this is rather pulling something out of the air. I'm afraid I don't know a more obvious route.

Comment: It's hard to say what is the easiest way. I would personally solve this the following way: $\int \sec x dx = \int \frac{1}{\cos x} dx = \int \frac{\cos x}{\cos^2 x} dx = \int \frac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2 x} dx = \int \frac{1}{1-y^2} dy$, where $y=\sin x$.

Comment: "It feels like pulling something out of the air". Isn't this the same as *trying different things and seeing if something works*, aka *trial and error*, which is what a lot of maths is like? If you didn't trial and error then you wouldn't be able to figure it out...

Comment: So: your question is whether the integral $\int_0^{\pi/6}$ is easier than the indefinite integral?

Comment: Interestingly, the integral of secant was *conjectured* in 1640 by Henry Bond, who compared computed values to a table of logarithms. This arose of work with Mercator map projections, and is a nice example of familiarity fueling intuition. [This online article (via awwalker.com)](https://awwalker.com/2018/10/02/integrating-secant/) by A. W. Walker (2018) mentions this history, and notes that the first "modern" proof (by Isaac Barrow in 1670) amounted to the first instance of a partial fractions decomposition, namely of $\dfrac{\cos\theta}{1-\sin^2\theta}$.

Comment: Another approach which is fairly natural is to write $\int \sec x \, dx = \int \frac{2}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}} dx$ Now putting $u=e^{ix}$ gives $\int \sec x \, dx = -2i \tan^{-1} e^{ix} + C$. You can manipulate that into a more normal form, or work from there.

Comment: Another answer is $\operatorname{acoth}(2)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not difficult (and a standard exercise) to compute
$$
\int\frac{2}{\sin2t}\,dt=\int\frac{\cos^2t+\sin^2t}{\sin t\cos t}\,dt=
\int\Bigl(\frac{\cos t}{\sin t}+\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}\Bigr)\,dt=\log\lvert\tan t\rvert+c
$$
How do you transform a cosine into sine? Easy, with the complementary angle. So perform $x=\pi/2-2t$ and your integral becomes
$$
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/6} -\frac{2}{\sin2t}\,dt=\Bigl[\log\tan t\Bigr]_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4}=-\log(1/\sqrt{3})=\log\sqrt{3}
$$

Answer (score 7):

Let's make the famous $z=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ substitution. Then $\sec x=\frac{1+z^2}{1-z^2}$ and $dx=\frac{2dz}{1+z^2}$. Knowing that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{12})=2-\sqrt{3}$, we compute $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\sec{x}dx=\int_0^{2-\sqrt{3}}\frac{-2dz}{z^2-1}=\ln\left (\left|\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right|\right )|_0^{2-\sqrt{3}}=\ln\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-1}\right)=\ln(\sqrt{3}).$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\int \sec x\,dx= \int \frac{\sec^2x}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}}dx=\sinh^{-1}(\tan x)+C
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_0\frac{1}{1-u^2}du=\text{artanh}(u)$$
$$\int_0\frac{1}{\cos x}dx=\int_0\frac{1}{1-\sin^2 x}\cos x\,dx=\text{artanh}(\sin x)$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{1}{\cos x}dx=\text{artanh}(\sin(\pi/6))=\text{artanh}(1/2)$$

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $\int_0 f(x) \, dx$? I would guess you're applying FTC with $f(0)=0$, i.e.$$f(y)=f(0) + \int_0^y f(x)\,dx$$but your notation seems unconventional.

Comment: Yes, $F(x)=\int_a f(x)dx$ is the unique antiderivative of $f$ (on a neighbourhood of $a$) with $F(a)=0$.

Comment: (Note that $1/(1-u^2)$ is defined on $(-\infty,-1)\cup(-1,1)\cup(1,+\infty)$, while $\text{artanh}(u)$ is only defined on $(-1,1)$. The notation $\int_0$ helps by fixing the interval, as well as by fixing the constant of integration.)